# Find the sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given generating function $\ f(x)=(1-x)^{1/2} $  and I want to find it's sequence. Is there any method that I can use to solve that kind of problem?

Comment: You can look at its Taylor series expansion. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+of+sqrt(1-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can apply a [generalization of the binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem),

$$(x+y)^r=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{r}kx^{r-k}y^k\;,$$

where the binomial coefficient is defined for arbitrary $r$ and non-negative integers $k$ as

$$\binom{r}k=\frac{r^{\underline k}}{k!}=\frac{r(r-1)\ldots(r-k+1)}{k!}\;.$$

Replacing $x$ by $1$ and $y$ by $-x$, you get

$$(1-x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}k(-1)^kx^k\;,$$

so the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is given by

$$a_n=(-1)^n\binom{1/2}n\;.$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{1/2}n&=\frac1{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac12-k\right)\\
&=\frac1{n!}\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\ldots\left(-\frac{2n-3}2\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{2^nn!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^nn!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}}C_{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

for $n\ge 1$, where $C_n$ is the $n$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), so

$$a_n=-\frac{C_{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}}--\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}$$

for $n\ge 1$, and clearly $a_0=\binom{1/2}0=1$.